# Python request.post Missing Required Param

Tags: python, request

I've been looking around and trying to get a post request to work, but I haven't found any luck. I keep getting a `MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAM` each time the request is being made. My following code is shown below.

```
def create_sign_group(group_name, header, url):

    temp_header = header
    temp_header['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    temp_header['Accept'] = 'application/json'

    data = {
        "GroupCreationInfo": {
            "groupName": group_name
        }
    }

    res = requests.post(url + 'groups', headers=temp_header, data=json.dumps(data))

    if res.status_code == 200:
        print('{} Group Created...'.format(group_name))
    else:
        print(res.status_code)
        print(res.headers)
        print(res.text)
        exit(res.status_code)
```

I've tried using `json` instead of `data`, but still getting the same error. Using a the REST API client I was able to successfully make the call. The rest client is shown below:
[image]
If anyone can point shine some knowledge and point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it. Take care.

Comment: this may be unrelated (i'm not sure) but why do you add data to `temp_header` and then never use it again?

Comment: I meant to user it in the `headers=temp_headers` param, but I forgot to change it out. However, still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign `headers=temp_header` not `headers=header`. `MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAM` is often griping about the content type header, which, as you can see IS being included in your screenshot test.

Comment: Good catch, I thought I changed it, but didn't. However, After changing it to `headers=temp_header` I'm still getting me the same error.

Comment: Do you have the right token(s) in your existing `header`? If you print out your header and compare it to the API, there should be a missing key somewhere in your header

Comment: Yeah, the only token needed is the access-token, which is correct, because I'm able to use the main header on other API calls in the program.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, I guess I was passing the wrong payload into the data param. I changed the code to:

```
data = {
        "groupName": group_name
    }
```

It looks like I didn't need the `"GroupCreationInfo"` parameter.